# Android Youtube : Video turns black

Tags: android, youtube-javascript-api

I was working on YouTube player in my Android app using the Javascript API. I had faced some issue, which I raised on a separate question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34786950/android-youtube-remove-buffering-indicator

I have faced another problem that sometimes on Samsung Note 4, the Youtube video becomes invisible, though the webview for Youtube is visible. Here are a couple of screenshots:
[image] [image]

As evident from the screenshot, the YouTube ads and subtitles are completely visible, but the video itself is not.

Can anyone point out a solution, or a possible cause why this is happening?

PS : I have not added the code in this question, because the code is the same as this question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34786950/android-youtube-remove-buffering-indicator

Comment: `I was working on YouTube player in my Android app using the Javascript API` why? You got native Android API for that.

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski When I started this, the Youtube developer docs mentioned several ways and it did not mention that one was better than the other. So, I chose the Javascript API as it looked faster to implement. Moreover, I am facing these problems only after I have completed the implementation. I could have faced similar or other problems with any other implementation as well